# Is the PADDD instruction actually supported by MMX, even though it's missing from Intel's manual?

Tags: assembly, x86, mmx

I wrote this code in NASM:

```
PADDD mm0, mm1
```

And it was assembled with no errors, but this instruction, though it exists in NASM, I couldn't find it in Intel Instructions Manuals, all I found is this:

```
PADDD xmm1, xmm2/m128
```

Which takes an `xmm` register and not an `mm` register.
This is the opcode of `PADDD mm0, mm1`: *0FFEC1*
And this is the opcode of `PADDD xmm0, xmm1`: *660FFEC1*
So why `PADDD mm0, mm1` is missing in Intel's Instructions manuals?

Comment: I don't know your source, but it exists [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_226.html).

Comment: @BenSteffan I found it here too : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings.  
But in the manual, it doesn't exist.

Comment: You seem to be correct. In the latest [Intel manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.html) the mmx variant is notably absent. In an older version of the [Intel manual from 2005](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/05au-cs240c/lab/ia32/IA32-2B.pdf) it is listed.

Comment: For the record, it's also present in the march 2017 volume 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple case of a typo/omission in the current version of Intel's manuals.

On [this site](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PADDB:PADDW:PADDD.html), which hosts a copy of the Intel docs (although not necessary the latest Intel docs), the opcode for `MMX` is present:

> ```
> Opcode/Instruction    Op/En                64/32 bit Mode Support     CPUID Feature Flag  Description
> 0F FC /r1            PADDB mm, mm/m64 RM  V/V                        MMX                 Add packed byte integers from mm/m64 and mm.
> ```

You will also find it in [an older Intel manual from 2005](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/05au-cs240c/lab/ia32/IA32-2B.pdf), as well as in the March 2017 version.

Nothing to see here; please move along.